# Schemaless Driver Options?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So i'm a bit conflicted. I want a quality driver/library to access that is also Schemaless, but it seems the only active MongoDB library for Nodejs is Mongoose.

Now, Mongoose is great and all, but again.. it's a Schema based library, and i don't want to use one with Mongo for this project.

So, the options i have found that fit my criteria (not Mongoose) are as follows..

- Mongodb Native

  - Probably the most widely used option, and the foundation for other libraries, but not the most friendly. The deeply nested callbacks can quickly become ugly, im my opinion.
- MongoSkin

  - This is a decent option, and it appears to allow a lot of access to normal Mongo constructs, but at the same time it is poorly documented and not all that active.
- Mongolian

  - My personal preference.. but it lacks access to much of Mongo's constructs, and the project seems nearly dead.. It's basically had no activity in a year.
- Mongojs

  - Likely the most recently active between the three wrappers, but it lacks GridFS support *(that i see)*.

Are there any other options i am missing?

**edit**: Adding other libs to the list..

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend you look at either:

1. Directly using the native node.js library [mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/index.html) (upon which all these are based).
2. [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs), which minimally wraps the native library to emulate the official mongodb API as much as possible.

Comment: I knew about Mongo-Native, but i stayed away from it due to it's level of verobseness. However, i have not heard of Mongojs, thank you! Would you recommend anything of these libraries?